# Countdown Timer on J2ME Canvas

Tags: canvas, java-me

In my Application, I need the Countdown timer(like a chronometer in Android) which is implemented on Canvas and display the countdown time to the user.
How can I implement Countdown Timer on Canvas and display the Countdown time to the user?

Comment: From your questions it looks like you have not tried anything. :( Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very easy, you simply need to use two classes `TimerTask` and `Timer` class. The `TimerTask` class is a thread which will execute your particular code while `Timer` is the class which tells `TimerTask` when to perform the code defined init. Just study the following code,

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerDemo
{
    private MyTimerTask mt;
    private Timer timer;

    public TimerDemo()
    {
        mt = new MyTimerTask();     
        timer = new Timer(); 
        timer.schedule(mt, 1000, 1000);
        System.out.println ( "Countdown Begins " ); 
    }

    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        TimerDemo td = new TimerDemo();
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        int val = 10;
        public void run()
        {
            if ( val > 0 )
            {
                System.out.println ( "Value : " + val-- );
            }
            else
            {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}

/*************************/
/**********OUTPUT*********
Countdown Begins 
Value : 10
Value : 9
Value : 8
Value : 7
Value : 6
Value : 5
Value : 4
Value : 3
Value : 2
Value : 1
*************************/
```

Comment: Lucifer::: I want to implement the countdown for java mobile application.So, please give me help regarding J2ME. Also thanks for this help.

Comment: Lucifer:: I have managed the code for working on J2ME Midlet and made a  form to display the Countdown Time. Now My question is, how can I implement these timer and timertask functionality on Canvas and how can I display it through Canvas?

Comment: you can append the output on canvas, so that it will display time there.

Comment: Lucifer:: I implemented timer through Canvas, but on Canvas, it just display the starting value of val(=10). It will not go in the loop and can't update the value.Please give me steps for implementing it on Canvas and update the countdown.

Comment: try repainting the canvas, it will display like it is updating the value.

Comment: what happened ? wasn't my answer helpful for you ?

Comment: Your answer is helpful to me and I had done according to your instruction and code. What happend?

Comment: are yaar.. then why you de-accepted my answer , em puchhu(ask) chhu.

Comment: Actually i am new on stackoverflow.So,getting done mistake sometimes.

Comment: Lucifer:: In my application, I need to use contdown timer in multiple Canvas class,But the Countdown timer works in only one Canvas. In other canvas countdown timer doesn't work.I need the countdown timer works for every Canvas.So,what are the steps for implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use java.util.TimerTask or java.util.Timer and implement The Runnable interface to create a thread.
Google it and see the documentation.